# How to log outgoing SAML requests in Spring security SAML2 service provider?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-saml2

I have a SAML client, implemented by Sring security SAML2 service provider extension. I was able to log SAML responses by setting appropriate logging level of my log4j:

```
<logger name="org.opensaml.saml" level="DEBUG" />
```

I would like to log also outgoing SAML requests (their XML version), but I wasn´t able to find any way to do that.
Any suggestions?